# JEST testing of a Sagas call

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-redux, jestjs, redux-saga

completely new in JEST testing framework, and I face a very straight forward issue with a sagas test. Looking around I figured out that in order to test a sagas that makes a API call, I have to mock it using `jest.mock`.

so here is my code in a shell:

```
export function* getSomething() {
  const url = 'http://localhost:4000/users/'
  const list = yield call(whatwgFetch, url)
  yield put(setListClients(list))
}
```

with `setListClients` being an action and `whatwgFetch` being exported from a utils/fetch file like this:

```
export const whatwgFetch = (url, options) => {
  return fetch(url, options)
    .then(response => checkStatus(response).text())
    .then(body => JSON.parse(body))
}
```

my test looks like:

```
import { call } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { setListClients } from 'app/actions'
import { getSomething } from './watchSomething'

const whatwgFetch = jest.mock('utils/fetch')

describe('Testing a saga', () => {
  const generator = getSomething()

  it('must call whatwgFetch', () => {
    const testValue = generator.next().value
    expect(testValue).toEqual(call(whatwgFetch, 'http://localhost:4000/users/'))
  })
})
```

problem, my test output tells me:

```
Expected value to equal:
  {"@@redux-saga/IO": true, "CALL": {"args": ["http://localhost:4000/users/"], "context": undefined, "fn": [Function bound fn]}}
Received:
  {"@@redux-saga/IO": true, "CALL": {"args": ["http://localhost:4000/users/"], "context": null, "fn": [Function anonymous]}}
```

`function` and `context` are not matching. What do I do wrong? I'm unsure if the problem comes from the mock of whatwgFetch, the whatwgFetch itself, the call etc...

Any feedback welcome.

Comment: It seems to me that jest.mock('utils/fetch') is just a different function than the original whatwgFetch. I don't think you need to mock it in this case as it isn't actually called.

Comment: hey Martin thanks for your comment. I `export default whatwgFetch` from utils/fetch.js file. How come they aren't the same? And yes it doesn't get called so you suggest I just import it and test as is?

Comment: It is not about how you export it, but rather how you import it. I suspect that calling `jest.mock('utils/fetch')` replaces the fetch function with jest mock function. As to the testing, yep I think testing it as it is might work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
`jest.mock('redux-saga/effects', () => {
  const originalModule = jest.requireActual('redux-saga/effects');

  return {
    __esModule: true,
    ...originalModule,
    call: jest.fn((fn, ...rest) => ({ args: rest, fn: jest.fn() }))
  };
});`
```